# VBA - Resgatar o valor de uma variável de um site

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Boa noite pessoal!

Estou iniciando no VBA e fiz uma macro que retorna as informações de um site pro Excel, porém estou ajustando algumas coisas e me deparei com um problema há uns 2 dias e não consigo resolver:

Para fins do objetivo do meu projeto, estou setando todas as tabelas ("tr) do site:

```
Set tabela = ie.document.all.tags("tr")
```

E quando inspeciono a variável tabela ele me retorna uma variável long:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando copiar esse valor "12" para uma variável do VBA e depois para o uma célula do Excel, mas nem o primeiro passo estou conseguindo.

Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui fazer o teste na sua aplicação porque está bem vaga.

Mas se você quer conseguir a quantidade de `tags` de linha de tabela `<tr>` de um código HTML o jeito mais fácil é usar `.GetElementsByTagName("tr")`

A variável pronta para usar na célula aqui no exemplo é `nTR`
Você poderia definir por exemplo:

```
Sheets("SuaPlanilha").Range("A1").Value = nTR

Sub teste()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim colTR As Object
Dim colTD As Object
Dim tr As Object
Dim td As Object]

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp"

'wait for page to load
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = IE.Document
Set colTR = doc.GetElementsByTagName("tr")

For Each tr In colTR
    nTR = nTR + 1
Next tr

IE.Quit

'Resultado
MsgBox nTR

End Sub
```